# IE is not supporting background image property

Tags: html, css

my code

```
<span class="iconCloud deactiveImage" src=""></span>
```

CSS

```
.deactiveImage {
            background-image: url("./Images/off.png");
            height: 35px;
            width: 35px;
        }
```

the pic is not displayed in IE. please help.. correct in chrome and firefox

Comment: IE most certainly *does* support `background-image`. The only issue I can see in your code is that `span` elements won't respect `height` and `width` by default because they're `inline`, but that's a cross-browser standard, and the background should still work anyway. Perhaps you could give more info, such as which IE versions, and maybe a jsFiddle example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: problem solved with below answers
thnks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`span` is an `inline` element by default, `height` and `width` won't be respected, so make it `block` or `inline-block`

```
.deactiveImage {
    background-image: url("./Images/off.png");
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use display:block in your css to display image  with the below css:

```
 <style type="text/css">
.deactiveImage {
        background-image: url("/Images/test.png");
        height: 35px;
        width: 35px;
        display:block;
    }
</style>
```